# how to get current csv row number in magento2?

Tags: magento2, csv

I want to add condition on rownumber :

like if ($row==1){
echo "test";
}
else{
echo "done";
}

file path:Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Source\csv

```
protected function _getNextRow()
{
    $parsed = $this->_file->readCsv(0, $this->_delimiter, $this->_enclosure);
    if (is_array($parsed) && count($parsed) != $this->_colQty) {
        foreach ($parsed as $element) {
            if (strpos($element, "'") !== false) {
                $this->_foundWrongQuoteFlag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $this->_foundWrongQuoteFlag = false;
    }


    return is_array($parsed) ? $parsed : [];
}
```

i want set condition like below in this function :

```
     if($row==0)
    {
         $parsed[]= 
   \Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product::COL_TYPE;
    $parsed[]= 
    \Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product::COL_ATTR_SET;
    $parsed[]= self::COL_ATTR_SET;
    }else{
$parsed[]=something else;
         }
```

}

Comment: You can execute your csv in foreach and have a counter incremented in it for the current index. like $i; and in the foreach $i++;

Comment: Have any other way because looping is not possible in my code?

Comment: Can you share your code little bit ?

Comment: @AnsarHusain i have added code in question please check if you can help me

Comment: Sorry I have to delete my answer.

Comment: can you share the classname of `$this->_file` please?

Answer (score 0):

Use $this->_key at the place of $row.

like as if($this->_key==0)

Comment: did you try this @Rutvee Sojitra ?